# Making multiple HTTP requests to Okta API via requests python lib

Tags: python

I am relatively new to programming outside of bash scripting so any tips would be much appreciated.

I am working on a python script to call the [Okta Group API](https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/groups/) to essentially make a list of groups via a yaml file.

I am using the requests library and a `for` loop to do this. The script only makes the last item I pass in from the yaml file. Am I not using the for loop properly?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import requests
import yaml

url = "https://org.okta.com/api/v1/groups"

headers = {
  "Accept": "application/json",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "Authorization" : "SSWS AUTHKEY",
  "User-Agent" : "Custom-Python-Agent"
}

with open(r'groups.yaml') as file:
    documents = yaml.full_load(file)

for okta_groups in documents['profile']['groups']:
    body = {'profile': {'name': okta_groups['name'], 'description': okta_groups['description']} }

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=body)
print(r)
```

YAML file:

```
profile:
  groups:
    - name: aws#test#api#001
      description: test description 1
    - name: aws#test#api#002
      description: test description 2
    - name: aws#test#api#003
      description: test description 3
```

Thank you!

Comment: Because you update "body" many times, and only use it to make 1 request at the very end.
You should indent the "r = requests..." and the print statement to be inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just indent these:

```
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=body)
print(r)
```

To be inside the loop:

```
for okta_groups in documents['profile']['groups']:
   body = {'profile': {'name': okta_groups['name'], 'description': okta_groups['description']} }

   r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=body)
   print(r)
```

That way, you will send a request for every instance of "body" rather than just the last one.